# Firebase PhoneAuth - multiple owners

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working on an app that makes use of Firebase Authentication to sign in users using the Phone number. The app runs fine on my device and I'm able to receive an OTP and authenticate. Now, the problem is that I have another friend of mine working on this app with me and I had given her the code through GitHub and she cloned the repo and tried to run the app, the app was able to run but the `onVerficationFailed` method was called and she was unable to authenticate. I have given her the ownership rights to the project on Firebase console but the app still doesn't authenticate at her end. Can someone please let me know what is missing here???

Comment: Did you add her SHA key to firebase console?

Comment: You mean I need to add two sha1 keys to this project, one from her side and the other from mine?

Comment: Ya her debug SHA will be different then yours

Comment: Thanks a bunch, it worked ;)